# Create table containing column names in order of highest value to lowest

Tags: r

I have a data set recording values for various metrics by name.  I want to sort these metrics for each name and use them to create a new data set with columns for each choice.  I have it to the point where i can sort the row, but i don't want the value, I want the name of the metric...

How can I get the column name to populate the cell instead of the value?

```
name <- c('jim', 'sal', 'xiu')
x <- c(100, 200, 100)
y <- c(300, 100, 300)
z <- c(400, 0, 200)

have <- data.frame(name, x, y, z)

choice1 <- c('z', 'x', 'y')
choice2 <- c('y', 'y', 'z')
choice3 <- c('x', 'z', 'x')

want <- data.frame(name, choice1, choice2, choice3)

attempt <- data.frame(t(apply(have, 1, sort, decreasing = TRUE)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach with `dplyr` tools:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(reshape2)
have %>% 
  # convert from wide to long format
  gather(metric, value, 
         -name) %>% 
  group_by(name) %>% 
  # arrange each group in descending order
  arrange(desc(value)) %>% 
  # with data arranged, the row number coincides with the ranking
  mutate(rank = sprintf("choice%s", row_number())) %>% 
  # recast to wide format
  dcast(name ~ rank, 
        value.var = "metric")
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that relies only on tidyverse.

```
library(tidyverse)

want <- have %>% group_by(name) %>% gather(var, value, 2:4) %>% 
  arrange(name, desc(value)) %>% mutate(choice = paste0("choice", row_number())) %>% 
  select(-value) %>% 
  spread(choice, var)
```